# postfix + dovecot error: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]:

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I setup a postfix/dovecot outgoing only mailing setup for my new mastodon instance.

My mail log:

```
Nov 20 04:51:57 simplysocial postfix/smtpd[23374]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 20 04:51:57 simplysocial postfix/smtpd[23374]: warning: unknown smtpd restriction: "spermit_sasl_authenticated"
Nov 20 04:51:57 simplysocial postfix/smtpd[23374]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration error; from=<notifications@simplysocial.online> to=<admin@simplycreate.online> proto=ESMTP helo=<simplysocial.online>
Nov 20 04:51:57 simplysocial postfix/cleanup[23378]: 8AC2622534: message-id=<20221120045157.8AC2622534@simplysocial.online>
Nov 20 04:51:57 simplysocial postfix/qmgr[23370]: 8AC2622534: from=<double-bounce@simplysocial.online>, size=1316, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 20 04:51:57 simplysocial postfix/smtpd[23374]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/6
```

my `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`:
https://pastebin.com/iwU6iFz5

`/etc/postfix/master.cf`:
[enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/F72GPxF8)

anyone have a clue what's going wrong and debug?

BTW i can successfully test sending from the commandline calling `mail`.

Comment: in particular i'm not certain where the user/password is being defined to be called from the client...

Comment: is there a way to attach from the localhost without authentication? where is this setting?

Comment: i guess the passwords have to do with this file `smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`?

Answer (score 0):

okay all good, basically i had to comment out some lines:
`/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
submission inet n - n - - smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

for completeness here's the mastodon config relating to smtp:

```
SMTP_SERVER=localhost
SMTP_PORT=587
SMTP_LOGIN=
SMTP_PASSWORD=
SMTP_FROM_ADDRESS=notifications@simplysocial.online
SMTP_AUTH_METHOD=plain
SMTP_OPENSSL_VERIFY_MODE=none
SMTP_ENABLE_STARTTLS_AUTO=true
```

And here's my original reference: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/postfix_and_dovecot_sasl/